# How to convert list of uint16 to byte array and write to binary file without adding null terminators for zero

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list of uint16 which I'm trying to write into a binary file. I do have a 0 in the beginning of the list for which it is adding a null terminator.How do I convert my list to able able write to the binary file correctly ?

```
  List<UInt16> xyz = new List<UInt16>();
  Byte[] byteArray = null;
  byteArray = xyz.SelectMany(i => BitConverter.GetBytes(i)).ToArray();
  Using(BinaryWriter Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(path))
  {
  Writer.Write(byteArray);
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect to be written instead of a `'\0'` if your list contains a `0x0000`?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? Of course if one `ushort` (a.k.a. `UInt16`) in the `List<>` has _either_ the upper eight bits _or_ the lower eight bits all zeros, then one byte (octet) becomes zero. And if the `ushort` is zero, two bytes are zero. What do you want to happen in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

BinaryWriter is simply writing the corresponding bytes to the file. The null terminator is simply a byte equal to all zeros, or `'\0'`.  If you cannot have a byte of all zeros, you will need to encode the zeros. A simple method would be to convert all `0x00`s to `0xFF01` and any actual `0xFF` to `0xFFFF`.  When reading the file, you will have to keep this in mind and decode it properly.

```
  List<UInt16> xyz = new List<UInt16>();
  Byte[] byteArray = null;
  byteArray = xyz.SelectMany(i => BitConverter.GetBytes(i)).ToArray();
  using (BinaryWriter Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create("path")))
  {
     foreach (Byte b in byteArray)
     {
        if (b == 0)
        {
           Writer.Write(Byte.MaxValue);
           Writer.Write((Byte) 1);
        }
        else if (b == Byte.MaxValue)
        {
           Writer.Write(Byte.MaxValue);
           Writer.Write(Byte.MaxValue);
        }
        else
        {
           Writer.Write(b);
        }
     }
  }
```